# Setting all reference to an object to null

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

I have this example code which is incomplete because I don't know how to do what I'm trying to do.

```
    // This class will never be garbage collected
    // It is the core to my Game Engine Loop.
    public class Application
    {
        HybridObject obj1;
        HybridObject obj2;
        List<Test> tests = new List<Test>();

        public Application()
        {
            obj1 = new HybridObject();
            obj2 = obj1;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Test test = new Test();
                test.obj = obj1;
                tests.Add(test);
            }

            obj1.Delete(); // This line should Null all properties using obj1 as a value.

            while (true)
            {
                CheckIfNull();
            }
        }

        void CheckIfNull()
        {
            if (obj1 == null) Console.WriteLine("Destroyed 1");
            if (obj2 == null) Console.WriteLine("Destroyed 2");

            foreach (var t in tests)
            {
                if (t.obj == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Destroyed From List");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Test
    {
        public HybridObject obj;
    }
```

```
    public class HybridObject
    {
        public void Delete()
        {
            // SET ALL REFERENCES THAT POINT TO THIS HYBRIDOBJECT TO NULL
        }
    }
```

## Smaller Example

If we just abstract away the mess of my code. The question boils down to this, how do I set everything that used obj to null in the example below?

```
HybridObject obj = new HybridObject();
List<HybridObject > objects = new List<HybridObject>();
objects.Add(obj);
objects.Add(obj);
obj = null; // If I set this all obj's in the list would be null as well.
```

## Explanation

Now let me explain, I'm making a basic game engine.

I'm trying to set all references to the HybridObject I created to null using a Delete method. When I call obj1.Delete() the 'Application' obj1, obj2 properties and all the 'Test' obj properties need to be set to null because I set the obj1 property to a new HybridObject(), then set all the other property values such as obj2 to obj1.

When I call obj1.Delete(); everything that points to the (obj1)HybridObject should now become null. Then the HybridObject can be garbage collected eventually because of no more references. Settings obj1 = null; doesn't solve this problem because it wont set the other references to null.

The obj1 property can be passed anywhere like into another class property, a list, struct, etc. So how would I handle setting everything to null without manually tracking all the references? The HybridObject will never be destroyed because there will still be strong references to it.

So what if during the runtime of my application I've created millions of objects over time and none of them have been destroyed because of the strong references they hold. What if that one HybridObject I created in application 'obj1' is passed into millions of other places such as collections over time? (This is all theoretical of course)

The question is. How do I remove ALL references or pointers to an object so it can be garbage collected? I'm unsure if this is even possible.

## Things I have tried

1. I found a solution using reflection but it becomes really complex when considering how HybridObject could be stored such as properties, collections, structs, etc, then it has to run over EVERY object instance I've created at runtime. It's not very fast so I don't think this is a good idea.
2. Tried creating an object Instance property inside of HybridObject, then making everything reference that Instance property, when I set that Instance property to null I wanted all things that pointed to that Instance property to reflect that change and become null. But I couldn't get it working.

Comment: _"When I call obj1.Delete(); everything that points to the (obj1)HybridObject should now become null"_ - you can't do that. Not directly anyway. You could put it in a container which you mark as disposed, but a reference is a reference and that keeps the object it points to alive, either directly or indirectly. You probably have an XY problem. Why do you pass a reference around so much, why does your code keep so much state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# references and setting them to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76018918/c-sharp-references-and-setting-them-to-null)

Comment: @CodeCaster Because I'm unsure of any other way to do this. Unity Game Engine allows you to do this and will clear up any references (set them to null) after obj1 was Destroyed. This is not my workflow, rather a workflow I want to mimic because it's one I'm comfortable with from using Unity which allows this type of behaviour

Comment: Ah, I see. But the problem is caused by your design, by how you wrote your code (maybe not realizing how a garbage-collected runtime works), and now you want to change how garbage collection works. I think it's more productive to accept that you're probably keeping to many references/lists around. Allowing to destroy an object that other code still points to is a (NullReferenceException) disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes of course it is, but when I'm developing my games with this engine there would always be checks if an object still exists like you would in Unity, its easy to avoid if you just do a check if object != null. It can be very useful to have a system like I've explained

Comment: It's just not possible (without hacking into pointers or into the runtime, AFAIK). Setting a reference to null just _sets that reference to null_, the object it used to point to still exists. Maybe (probably) Unity has their own extensions into the runtime and/or GC.

Comment: You know about weak references? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/weak-references

Comment: @rene yes I do. They are not helpful to me. Unless I can some how wrap HybridObject into a weakreference. And still just use "HybridObject obj;" in Application (but it would be a weakreference) which I don't think is possible... Otherwise its just a huge mess for end users.

Having "WeakReference<HybridObject> obj" everywhere is just too much writing.

I need to just have "HybridObject obj"

Comment: There is no nice way of doing this. This is not supported by the runtime and I would argue that kind of breaking a lot of good code practices. Obviously you can try hacking the runtime - in theory it can be done by finding the reference and scanning trough memory but it can be very brittle and I would argue will require quite some time to implement which will overweight the benefits. Or you can do some assembly weaving magic using Fody so any assignment will perform reference counting but both problems still persist.

Comment: @CodeCaster not an Unity expert here, but AFAIK they have they own runtime with a lot of quirks and specific magic. And `== null` has quite some unexpected to "ordinary" C# dev meaning - see [this](https://blog.unity.com/technology/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm comfortable with from using Unity which allows this type of behaviour

Unity is a completely different runtime where null check is not actually checking if the reference is a null reference (i.e. it points to "empty memory") - see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62678228/2501279), i.e. 1) it does not mean that all memory occupied by the object can be GCed (hence all the problems you can have in "vanilla" C# which you are trying to avoid) 2) it is possible to get `true` for `this == null` ([see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72069139/2501279)) which is something that does not make much sense from "vanilla" C# point of view.

> its easy to avoid if you just do a check if object != null.

If what you are asking for would be possible, it would not be easy to avoid. Especially in multithreaded environment. Hence if any reference can be nullified at any moment there is no way to guarantee that after the check the reference is not actually null (unless using some magic locking which can potentially kill all performance and cause deadlocks).

So in summary, for anything that inherits `UnityEngine.Object` comparison with null does not mean what you think it actually means, so you can consider following options:

1. Follow the pattern from Unity - exposed API classes are wrappers around internal resources which can be cleared and creating base class with custom `==` which will "fake" nulls.

   - Personally I would consider `IDisposable` pattern for this (maybe with a small difference with usual implementation - not throwing when something is called on disposed object but making it no-op, but that is debatable)
2. Design some API to register some callback for `obj1.OnDelete` so the user code can do what is necessary, though I would argue that it can quickly become too cumbersome
3. Since you will need to rely on the developer to clean up in some way at some point (i.e. release references to the "wrappers") maybe it can be worth to rely on this completely at least for some basic game engine.

Read more:

- [Unity Blog: Custom == operator, should we keep it?](https://blog.unity.com/technology/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it)

Comment: The best answer anyone has given me!!

Comment: @LJH was glad to help! If answer works for you - feel free to mark answer as accepted one.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. But the idea of what you mentioned, plus the link to that Unity blog is really helpful. So I will mark as answered because this is probably the best I'm going to get. Although an example would go the extra mile!